# Rails slim rendering html as text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, slim-lang

I am using Rails 6 & [rails-slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails)

When I try to render a rails form using the code below:

```
== form_for model, url: messages_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.text_field :body
  = f.submit
```

It outputs raw html as a string for the input tag i.e. this html appears as a string in the browser instead of actually rendering an input/button:

```
<input type="text" name="message_thread_message[body]" id="message_thread_message_body" /><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Message" data-disable-with="Create Message" />
```

When I inspect the elements using developer tools, I can see that the rest of the form renders as proper html elements.

The slim gem versions are:

- slim (4.1.0)
- slim-rails (3.2.0)

Have I missed any config step?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `= form_for model` (instead of `==`)?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma. I have tried this as well but still giving the same result

Comment: Are you rendering a partial? If so, what's the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Output without HTML escaping `==` is same as the single equals sign `=`, but does not go through the escape_html method. Ref [this](https://github.com/slim-template/slim)
Following should work

```
= form_for model, url: messages_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.text_field :body
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but unfortunately, it is still doing the same. Copied your snippet and pasted it to make sure that I got it 100% right

Comment: While rendering this you have to add `==` for ex `== render 'some_partial'`